# How do I integrate xAPI or cmi5 in my Django application?

Tags: django, lms, xapi

I have all the user's activity data like course completion data, course topic completion data, time spent on each topic and course, assessment data in MySQL database. But, I couldn't find the documentation/tutorial on integrating cmi5 (with/without xAPI) into Learning Management System platform built using Django web-framework.

So, far I have learned a little about the cmi5 from the below links,

1. https://risc-inc.com/cmi5-overview-process-flow/
2. https://xapi.com/cmi5/cmi5-technical-101/

Answer (score 0):

That's a very broad question. The broad answer is you need to set up a learning record store (LRS), then configure your Django app to connect to the LRS for sending/getting statements. Note that CMI5 is a subset of xAPI, you can't use CMI5 without xAPI, and xAPI requires an LRS.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to set up a learning record store (LRS) for a Django app?

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works -- if you have a specific question or issue, we can help diagnose it. For general and broad how-tos, you'll need to do your own research online. For xAPI the best place to start is by getting an LRS then digging into their documentation. https://xapi.com/get-lrs/